# Cant interate through overflow in an unorderd map

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable, unordered-map

As far as I understand both the boost:unordered_map and std::unordered_map work the same in terms of "overflow" (aka multiple things that get inserted with the same key). They store it in a "bucket" so you can then iterate over them.

For example:

```
key:   data:
"apple" 2
"peach" 4
"apple" 3
"peach" 8
```

then the bucket for "apple" would contain 2 & 3, right?

Well I am having trouble acessing these things.

Here is my code:

```
#define ANZ 10
typedef boost::unordered_map<uint16_t, int> uuidMap_int;


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    uuidMap_int uuidMap;
    boost::uuids::uuid entity1;
    boost::uuids::uuid entity2;

    for(unsigned int i = 0;i<ANZ;i++)
        uuidMap.insert(std::pair<int,int>((i<5?0:1),i));

    for(unsigned int i = 0;i < uuidMap.bucket_count();i++){
        for(uuidMap_int::local_iterator it = uuidMap.begin(i); it != uuidMap.end(i);++it){
            std::cout<<it->first<<"|"<<it->second<<"\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

All it does is make 2 new entries to the map and filling them.
Here is what the output is supposed to look like:

```
0|0
0|1
0|2
.
.
.
1|5
1|6
.
.
.
1|10
```

But it actually looks like this

```
0|0
1|5
```

Now I dont know why this is happening. It seems like the "overflow" simply gets trashed. However I am trying to make sth simmilar to a small database, so I need a way to have a id and a bunch of data belonging to said id in a map like this.

What am I doing wrong/what other map allows me to work the way I want to?

Comment: What is happening is your understanding is wrong. Other than that, you aren't doing anything wrong.

Comment: @juanchopanza care to explain where I am wrong or are you just gonna leave me hanging here?

Comment: Maybe read this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map. `unordered_map` holds key-value pairs. What you probably need is [`std::unordered_multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap).

Comment: @juanchopanza I did read that reference multiple times before but I was probably just too blind. Anyways std::unordered_multimap worked like a charm (I used boost but its basically the same). THANKS! (please post as an answer so I can tick it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (and what @juanchopanza tries to show) is that you have to read the documentation about a class, in order to use it correctly.  A map is a relationship between a key (the indexing key) and a value (the data stored).  In this case, you use only two keys (namely `0` and `1`) and each `insert()` you do to the map just **refuses to insert elements on the already two key cells with the new data**.  The expected behaviour is the one you get  (you use only two different keys, you have only two cells with data), the first entries you inserted with the only two keys you have used, each.  `Multimap` classes allow you to have *several entries with the same key*, so you will get all your elements inserted properly.

But the other question that remains is why to use a `map` if you don't use the functionality it offers to you.  The map allows you to differentiate the elements by key, so normally, you don't insert (perhaps only in multimaps, where you cannot differentiate elements by key) but `put()` the elements and index them by key (with the `[]` operator)?

Please, read thoroughly the documentation about each class.